# Installation of Biovia DS visualiser on ubuntu

Tags: protein-structure

I am trying to install Biovia DS visualiser2021 on ubuntu 22.04. I used the procedure from the following website

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175772/cant-install-discovery-studio-visualizer

When I run the installer `./install_DSClient.sh` I got the following error

```
Calling LicensePack Installer 

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
```

`Uncompressing License Pack and extracting files, please wait..`.

./install_lp.sh: 73: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

`Copying 1 files to ./share/license/data/tempdata.dat Please wait.`..
`Copying 1 files to /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/Logs/dsclientinstall.log Please wait..`.

```
Completed installing  DiscoveryStudio2021 at /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021

Check log file [ /home/user/BIOVIA/DiscoveryStudio2021/Logs/dsclientinstall.log ] for more information. Return code: 0
```

How to solve this error?